# How to use Firefox in tor bundle independently?

Tags: firefox, tor

How to use Firefox in the TOR browser bundle independently without need of connecting to TOR network so that it can be used as regular Firefox browser for fastest 28 Mbps fiber net

I try removing tor button-and other features in tor browser after launch but it is not connecting to internet

Firefox from mozzilla is great for privacy

Comment: Why not just download stand-alone Firefox instead of the TOR bundle?

Answer (score 0):

When you open TOR Firefox, goto Addons and open Preferences of Torbutton. In the end there is an option,"Disable Button and Hotkeys to prevent accidental toggle".

Uncheck that option and click the dropdown menu of Torbutton and click "Toggle tor status".

Try to surf the internet now, you'll be using non Tor network with TOR Firefox